# Outlook does not work with HTML

Tags: html, outlook

My `Outlook 2010` does not work with my `HTML5` code.
It works fine with `Gmail` and `Hotmail`.

The problem is that Outlook spreads the whole code over the whole page. and does not align the code correctly. 
Can anyone help me to solve my problem and or at least tell me what I am doing wrong?
My code is:

```
 <!--Row 1-->
 <tr style="position:fixed; width:794px;height:200px; margin-left:1050px;">
       <td class=uni STYLE="margin-top: 18px;margin-left:1000px;height:17px;width:41px;">L</td>
 </tr>

 <!--Row 2-->
 <tr style="position: fixed; margin-left:  750px;">
       <td class=uni STYLE="top:32px;left:655px;height:34px;width:96px;font-size:22pt; " >Lossen</td>
 </tr>

 <!--Row 3-->
 <tr style="position: fixed; margin-top: 100px ">
       <br>
       <td class=uni STYLE="top:128px;left:56px;height:17px;width:20px;">Bonnummer</td>
       <td class=uni STYLE="top:127px;left:130px;height:17px;width:85px;"> Numbers</td>
       <br>
       <td class=uni STYLE="position: inherit; top:127px;left:537px;height:17px;width:40px; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 90px">Datum</td>
       <td class=uni STYLE="position: inherit; top:127px;left:580px;height:17px;width:100px; margin-left: 105px; margin-top: 90px">29-10-2014</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Outlook uses MS Word to render HTML, and is notoriously bad at it. However, you haven't actually told us what is showing wrong in your example; please edit the question to be more specific than "does not work".

Comment: ow forgot that part. thanks

Comment: Oke I edited my Question. Is it now Better to understand??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook can't read HTML5 elements. Also using classes in an email is bad practice. It will look terrible in GMail, as GMail doesn't read style tags or external CSS.

As probably know Outlook uses Word (not IE) for rendering HTML markup. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)